# How to redirect desktop users away from mobile site... to regular site?

Tags: search, mobile, desktop, sniffer

How can I sniff out desktop users and send them to regular (non-mobile) site when they find the mobile site listed in google?

Thank you for any insight!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the HTTP-headers for the type of browser the user is using and redirect to the correct site. There is also a nifty framework for it; http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/

Comment: Thanks, but isn't there some simple sniffer javascript that I can put into the mobile pages to direct desktops to the fullsite?

Comment: Well if you are already using Zend Framework I would also recomment Zend_Http_UserAgent (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.user-agent.html)

Comment: No, Im just using simple javascript sniffer on the main site... detecting mobile and sending them to the mobile folder of the site.

Comment: so you could make an inverse of this sniffer and include that on the mobile site.

Comment: I have this for the iphone... how to modify for desktop?   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
<!--
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
  if (document.cookie.indexOf("iphone_redirect=false") == -1) window.location = "http://www.mysite.com/iphone/index.htm";
}
//-->
</script>

Comment: if((!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) && (!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) { window.location = "mysite.com/index.htm"; }

Comment: Thanks for your patience Martin. Much appreciated!... obviously, I am not a developer... but still trying my best. This should do the trick. Thx! (Plus, a good searchable thread for others)

Comment: No problem, we all need to start at the very beginning. And while helping others you learn a thing or two for yourself as well.

Answer (score 0):

Dave,

There's a [really interesting article about it on Google Central](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/11/running-desktop-and-mobile-versions-of.html). You should check it out.

While I'm aware that it doesn't answer your question, it's totally worth reading. As I'm on this very same quest, I'd appreciate if you could share with us whatever way out of this predicament you get to find.

By the way, can you post your website URL here for the rest of us to see? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use www.handsetdetection.com in reverse to redirect people from your mobile site back to your standard site.